# Adding sprite in PIXI Particles Container using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, pixi.js

I have a problem adding a Sprite to my PIXI Particles container in Vue.js. This works when I run PIXI only inside a script, but somehow in Vuejs every `new PIXI.Sprite.from("../assets/plainSquare.png")` don't show

My goal is to generate a static grid of square this way:

```js
setup() {
    // making a 30 x 16 grid of tiles
    const columns = 30;
    const rows = 16;
    for (let i = 0; i < columns * rows; i++) {
        const square = PIXI.Sprite.from("../assets/plainSquare.png");
        square.width = square.height = 25;
        square.x = (i % columns) * 32;
        square.y = Math.floor(i / columns) * 32;
        // add squares to stage
        this.container.addChild(square);
    }
}
```

If you need, here is the full codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pixi-sprite-loading-cn7re?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Path should be `"./assets/..."` on your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `require` for get the image:

```js
PIXI.Sprite.from( require("./assets/plainSquare.png"));
```

Comment: Do you know why vueJS needs require? Thanks btw

Comment: @Philx94 Because this code will be executed on client, after building, and at this context, assets folder doesn't exist. It could be ok if you are using a image inside public folder.